# Is there such a thing as the thinnest wrapper around a class to add methods?

Tags: c++, methods, overriding, wrapper

To my understanding, C++ doesn't feature a mechanism to add methods to an existing class (say, QString but please don't focus on the fact that's a Qt function) as ObjC does; let's assume those new methods do not require any new member variables. Instead, the only option is to create a wrapper class (say, KString) that inherits A and adds the required method(s) (say, toFoo()).

However, this requires modification everywhere where you want to use the new method, either something like

```
static_cast<KString*>(ptrToQStringInstance)->toFoo()
```

But if there are many places like that you'd like to be able to use `#define QString KString` in the relevant files (or do the equivalent search/replace).

Of course then you're going to run into errors like "no viable conversion to [const] KString from [const] QString" for which you'd have to add a copy constructor like

```
inline KString(const QString &that)
{
    *(static_cast<QString*>(this)) = that;
}
// add an assignment operator for good measure too
inline KTEStringView &operator=(const QString &other) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
{
    *(static_cast<QString*>(this)) = other;
    return *this;
}
```

My question:
- is there a well-defined and limited set of methods (independent of the parent class) that you'd have to implement (override) this way, or are you looking at overriding all methods that return a QString, trying very hard to avoid deep copies?
- is this the best approach or can you use language constructs that make this more "elegant" (e.g. `using` or some fancy kind of method assignment)?

Thanks!

Edit: why would you do this: when your existing class comes from an older version of a library, and you working with dependent code that would like to use things from a newer version of that library. In ObjC I have done this kind of extension regularly to add convenience methods to NSWindow or NSString so I could call them as if they were provided by the SDK, without having to cast to a dedicated child class or call a global function that takes the class instance as a parameter.

Edit2: here's another example, this time openly Qt related. It adds an alternative for `QQuickItem::size()` to Qt versions that do not yet have this:

```
template <class QtType>
class Q510QI : public QtType
{
public:
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 10, 0)
    QSizeF size()
    {
        return QSizeF(QtType::width(), QtType::height());
    }
#endif
};
#define Q510QIPCAST(instanceptr) static_cast<Q510QI<std::decay<decltype(*instanceptr)>::type>* >(instanceptr)
```

This allows me to replace `foo->size()` (where foo points to a QQuickItem or inherits it) with `Q510QIPCAST(foo)->size()`.

Evidently I could have done this with a free template function (which would not have needed decltype and std::decay) but that function would need to have an explicit implementation for the newer Qt versions (call the actual QQuickItem::size() method). If I wanted to add a series of other trivial methods I'd be adding as many `#if/#else/#endif`s whereas here I could just add those trivial functions between that single `#if/#endif`.

Comment: There's nothing similar to .net's [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) in C++. Though C++20 may have an answer to that through UFCS.

Comment: Extending `QString` doesn't seem like a good approach to me. Better try to explain what are you trying to achieve. Most probably you need some kind of helper method in your system that accepts `const QString&` as an argument and executes some operations on it. In most cases extending the existing type from the library is a terrible idea.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Re the first part of your question; casting QStrings to be your own class when they're not - even if you add no new variables, is UB.  So don't do that.  But why not have a wrapper that has contains a QString; and then offers a conversion operator to a QString?

Comment: You could do something [similar to this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190711-00/?p=102682) to detect if the member is present, and otherwise do the forward port. However that would be a free function, not a member

Comment: UKMonkey: I think you missed the fact Kstring inherits QString so casting should be safe. This inheritance also makes it possible to use the ew class wherever a QString is required. I’d like to avoid a class with a local QString member var as that opens up questions whether it should be a pointer, reference or copy (with all associated implications).

Comment: @Caleth interesting. Knowing when to “roll my own” isn’t really the problem here, though it would make it possible to use the non-ported API when the app is run against a newer version of the library. FWIW, clang has `@available` that could also be used for that — if one can extend it.

Comment: When you write something like `static_cast<KString*>(ptrToQStringInstance)->toFoo()` its just "syntactic sugar" equivalent of `KString::toFoo(ptrToQStringInstance)`, so I really don't understand why do all this hard and error prone work if you can just declare standalone function and call it "old" way...

Comment: @RJVB only if you are doing it to a KString, which is not the case for a number of situations. None of the QSomethingElse methods will be returning KStrings

Comment: @sklott: a standalone function would indeed be the simplest in case you're extending a class with a method of your own. That's not the case here. Since apparently we cannot forget that QString is not just an example class but also part of Qt, here's what I'm actually doing that prompted the question. I'm extending a class (QString) so that I can use it as a replacement for QStringView in a library that makes limited use of that class, and which I want to be able to build against Qt 5.9. I want to keep the number of #ifs down, in that library and in any future code that uses that library.

Comment: (continued) I may end up putting the actual QStringView implementation into a library of my own but that won't give me all the methods in related classes that take or return a QStringView. However, if I can #ifdef QStringView to QString (or rather, KString) then the affected code will instead be calling methods that take or return a QString, and as far as I can tell now those all exist.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't provide [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), as other languages (as C#) might propose.

C++ way is to add free functions or use inheritance.

[Uniform function call syntax](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4474.pdf) proposal might allow to have syntax you expect (with free functions way).

Comment: I am aware of that (my question starts off with that). I'm trying to figure out how you can get something that works almost as nicely. So, this is not an answer to my question, sadly.